# Fourier Transform of Triangle Wave in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm in my first computational physics course using Python and I'm completely stumped on a HW problem. I've been working on it for days now with no progress. The professor offered no assistance when I emailed.

The problem is as follows:
*Consider the sawtooth wave*
*f(x)=t, 0 < t < 0.5*
*f(x)= 1-t, 0.5 < t < 1*
*(a) Define this function using code.*
*(b) Find the Fourier transform.*
*(c) Plot the Fourier transform.*

That's exactly what is given. No examples provided. I just can't seem to figure out how to code the step function in a way that I can apply **np.fft.fft()**

My latest (poor) attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))

def f(x):
    X = 1.0
    if (0 < x < (X/2.)):
        return x
    elif ((X/2.) < x < X):
        return 1-x

t = np.arange(0.0,1.001,0.001)

FFT = np.abs(np.fft.fft(f(t)))
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(f.size,t[1]-t[0])

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t,np.array([f(x) for x in t]))
plt.xlim((-0.5,1.5))
plt.ylim((0.0,0.75))

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(freqs,np.log10(FFT),'x')
plt.show()
```

Of course this doesn't work.

Please! Any suggestions, comments, corrections, jokes, etc?

Comment: In `f`, what happens when `x` is exactly equal to `X/2` ?  Or when `x == 0`?  I'm not certain I know what your function returns, but it's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I'm fairly positive my attempt to even define the function is incorrect coded. When I simply ran the code without FFT I got a plot of a symmetric triangle (height 0.5, centered at 0.5), which is what I wanted. But when I try to do the fft on the function, errors.

Comment: hint: Simplify your expression to `if (x < X/2.0) return x else return 1-x`

Comment: (Sorry if this is a bit pedantic.)  Your function is a continuous function.  Is the assignment to find the *continuous* Fourier transform or the *discrete* Fourier transform?  The FFT provides the latter.

Comment: The only thing I have to go on is what my professor told us in class and he said use FFT. But like I said, I have NO idea if I'm anywhere close to being on the right track, given the problem at hand.

Comment: Every example I find online or in a book has a function in terms of sin or cos before using the np.fft function. I asked my prof if I had to do the FT for the step function analytically prior to using Python and he said no, do everything in Python. That's the only assistance that was given.

Comment: Here is my favourite source of DSP related info. The following link will teach you a bit about Fourier "stuff": http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/1.htm Technically speaking your teacher is innacurate in asking you to do a Fourier transform with a FFT.

Comment: As for your actual code, there is a lot to say: "import scipy.fftpack" is useless, you should use np.fft.rfft since your input is real. f(x) does not work the way you think, you cannot copy the mathematical definition "as is". You may use scipy.signal.sawtooth instead. The plotting in itself looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late now, I guess - but there's a super easy way to do this:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy import signal

# Number of sample points
N = 600
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0

y = signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 5 * x, width=.5)
yf = fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0*T), N//2)
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]))
plt.show()
```

see the docs for signal and fft for more information - this is just an appropriation of the examples from those pages.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sawtooth.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html